# How do I use Rails to find one has_many but not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

Message has_many user_messages.  It has two.

1 UserMessage will have the sender as user_id

The other UserMessage will have the receiver as user_id

Knowing one user, how can I, for any message, find the other?

Here's what I tried as a method to the Message class, but it fails:

```
 32   def other_user(one_user)      
 33     um = self.user_messages
 34     um.each do |user_message|
 35       
 36       output_user = User.find(user_message.user_id) unless user_message.user_id == one_user.id
 37     end
 38     
 39     return output_user
 40   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be implemented as an association enhancement. This will be efficient for high-volume of messages as it pushes processing to DB.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
    has_many :receivers, :through => :sent_messages, :source => :receiver do 
        def for_message(message_id)
            where("messages.id = ?", message_id)
        end
    end

    # Another association mapping for received_messages

end


class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
    belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"

end


#Usage
User.first.sent_messages

#all users received messages from first user
User.first.receivers

#all users received messages from first user for message of message_id
User.first.receivers.for_message(message_id)
```

Comment: Hi, when you have has_many :receivers, does that mean there needs to be a separate model receivers?

Comment: No - :receivers are just Users. This solution issues a single query to DB which reduces in-code processing time.

Comment: @Tamer -- what does it mean in your comment #Antoher association mapping for sent_messages? isn't that already defined with the has_many?  Or is that comment referencing the code above?

Comment: @Tamer, oh, how are we using the UserMessage class?  Each message has a UserMessage -- one for the sender and one for the user....instead of having sender_id and receiver_id in Message, I have it set up as UserMessages...that way, in case anything changes from say a sender and not a receiver....

Comment: @Angela - Sorry, the comment text was for received_messages (updated)

Comment: @Angela - This means a UserMessage has only a user_id, and probably a polymorphic user type 'Sender', 'Receiver'. My solution assumed a sender_id, received_id defined for each of the messages.

Comment: @Angela - the solution could probably be modified to use a UserMessage with a user type.

Comment: ah, I see, maybe I should change that to have a sender and receiver for each messsage then, I'm getting all kinds of different suggestions to do a message app.

Comment: could I create a method all_messages self.sent_messages + self.received_memssages?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there should be a better definition of who is the `sender` and who is the `receiver`, but in the meantime, what about:

```
def other_user(one_user)
  user_messages.reject do |msg|
    msg.user_id == one_user.id
  end.first.user
end
```

It takes the set of `user_messages`, filters out the one that belongs to `one_user`.  There should be one left in the array, so pick it out and return the user attached to it.

**EDIT**

I might not understand all your requirements, but I'd probably just add a `sender_id` and `receiver_id` directly to `Message` and remove the `UserMessage` join table.  Then you could define the relationship like:

```
class User
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
end

class Message
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want the intermediate table for tracking user-specific states, you could look into using STI to subclass `UserMessage` as `SentMessageLink` and `ReceivedMessageLink` (those names are not awesome -- but you get the idea), then you could use `has_many :through`.

```
class SentMessageLink < UserMessage
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :message
end

class User
  has_many :sent_message_links
  has_many :sent_messages, :through => :sent_message_links
end

class Message
  has_one :sent_message_link
  has_one :sender, :through => :sent_message_link
end
```

with similar code for received messages.  Then you should be able to access `sender` and `receiver` right from the message.

Comment: .. I see, thanks -- the reason I created the UserMessage table was because what if one party (for example, the sender) deletes or reads or changes the status of the message.  I guess I could have set up some kind of table for status?  Wuld that be better?